# FTP: How to get rid of "WARNING! 1 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode" message?

Tags: linux, ftp, shell, ups

I wrote a little shell script (on CentOS) to download statistics from our APC UPS device. It works great, but everyday cron sends an email with this message:

```
WARNING! 1 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode File may not have transferred correctly.
```

I also get that message when I get the file manually on the shell. The FTP part of my script looks like this:

```
ftp -in $ftpip <<END_FTP_DOWNLOAD
user $ftpuser $ftppassword
get data.txt
bye
END_FTP_DOWNLOAD
```

How can I get rid of this warning message which may disturb my colleagues?

The manual FTP connection looks like this. I tried to type "ascii" this time:

```
220 AP9617 Network Management Card AOS v2.6.4 FTP server ready.
Name (192.168.0.50:myusername): username
331 User name okay, need password.
Password:
230 User logged in, proceed.
ftp> ascii
200 TYPE Command okay.
ftp> get data.txt
local: data.txt remote: data.txt
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,50,161,31).
125 Data connection already open; transfer starting.
WARNING! 1 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode
File may not have transferred correctly.
226 Closing data connection.
131468 bytes received in 19,3 secs (6,6 Kbytes/sec)
ftp> bye
221 Thank you for using APC products!
```

The data.txt has between 500 and 800 lines and the last line is always empty.

Comment: If anyone is stumbling on this because of FTP missing from High Sierra and ran `brew install inetutils`, be sure to check out the following comment:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299758/how-to-get-bsd-ftp-and-telnet-back-in-10-13-high-sierra/312273#312273

Answer (score 11):

Try to use binary mode instead of ASCII mode. It should be something like:

```
ftp -in $ftpip << END_FTP_DOWNLOAD
user $ftpuser $ftppassword
bin
get $filename
bye
END_FTP_DOWNLOAD
```

Comment: this solution works fine and seems more reliable

Comment: But is close to useless for EBCDIC translation.

Answer (score 6):

Now i've found a (dirty) solution:

I download the textfile in BINARY mode and then replace the ^M character which gets inserted in the file since it looks like the APC UPS is based on DOS...

```
tr -d '\015' < data.txt > data-$today.txt
```

If someone comes up with a better solution it would be great, but this also works.